# AJAX: return true or false on 'success:'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX script, but for some reason the var ok it's not returning true or false so the form can continue:

```
function ajax_call(email,title,url){
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var parametros = {"emaail":email, "tiitle":title, "uurl":url};
    var ok = true;
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: 'validate.php',
        type: 'post',
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occurred! Try Again!");
        },
        success: function (response) {

            if(response == 'bien') { ok = true; } else { $("#ajax_cal").html(response); ok = false; }

        }
    });

return ok;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return ajax_call();">
...
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//////....
    if(!empty($errors)) { 
        foreach($errors as $error) { 
            echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
        }
    } else { echo 'bien'; }

?>
```

Everything works good, except for the return value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's not returning true or false, what is it returning?

Comment: Also, what does `response` return? Does it return "bien"?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, it's always going to return true because it doesn't wait for the response to potentially change the value.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - perfect answer :) His function might return a promise though and then use that promise when the request is fulfilled.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist so this is impossible? The response value will either return 'bien' or all the errors stored in an array. There's where I know if it's true or false depending on the value. It does everything good except for the validation.

Comment: @EduardoGo It's not impossible, no. You just need to account for the asynchronous nature of the AJAX request. Generally you'd handle the form submit, send the AJAX request, then suppress the submit event (`return false`). Then in your `success` callback you'd either display errors to the user or, if it was all OK, submit the form again and bypass the event handler (probably use a global flag for this).

Comment: Why can't you just `return ok;` in the `complete` callback (or `.done()` depending on your call structure). This accounts for the asynchronous nature that @AnthonyGrist is describing while always returning a value. The `complete` callback will fire after  ***success*** or ***failure*** so you should be okay to return it within that callback.

Comment: @War10ck Because you can't. the outer function has already returned true by that point in time due to the "asynchronous nature" of ajax.

Comment: @War10ck You can return anything you like from that function, but it essentially just vanishes into the aether - it's not returning to any of your code. And, as Kevin already said, the outer function has already returned at that point.

Comment: Well you'll have to remove the outer function return. Force the code to execute in the order you want. The `success`, `failure` or `complete` callback should call the next function or trigger the next event. Until the call returns don't do anything. Force the code to work in a semi-synchronous nature.

Comment: @War10ck But... it won't wait. If you don't return in the outer function, it will return `undefined`, it won't wait unless you make the ajax `async: false` which is a bad idea.

Comment: @KevinB Agreed on the _async_ part. It just seems like this is a poor design decision. Whatever, happens after the return could be easily wrapped in another function which only executes in one of the callbacks. (i.e. `ajax_call();`) would be the last statement in the function that invokes it). Then it would in essence sit idol until the call returned when it would invoke the next function in the callback. I definitely understand what you are saying though. Just seems like it shouldn't be that hard using all the callbacks available.

Comment: En espñaol mejor, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prevent the submit completely, send the ajax request, then if it's good, submit the form.

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
...
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
    // prevent submit
    e.preventDefault();

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var parametros = {"emaail":email, "tiitle":title, "uurl":url};
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: 'validate.php',
        type: 'post',
        context: this,
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occurred! Try Again!");
        },
        success: function (response) {

            if($.trim(response) == 'bien') { 
                this.submit(); // submit, bypassing jquery bound event
            } 
            else { 
                $("#ajax_call").html(response); 
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What errors did it give you or what didn't work about it? This is a pretty straight forward way of doing it, if something's going wrong, it's most likely due to the ajax request or or something external to this code.

Comment: I know it should work since the response will return 'bien' (good) OR will print the errors. They are only to options, no idea why is not working :(

Comment: Hey man, thanks! What I was missing is actually this line: $(document).ready(function() { });  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning ok at the end of your function. This is returned **before** your ajax request is sent and completed.

You cannot rely on the return value of your function, you should do something inside your "success" part. It basically depends on what you want to do with your return value

Comment: But what can I do if I'm just using 1 echo on my PHP... It's a validation form, if an array has errors it will echo the errors,, else it will echo 'bien'; so that's where response has 'bien' and it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete newbie to jquery but in some of the scripts I've been working on I've had to prefix the 'response' you have.

For instance...

```
if(response.tiitle == 'bien') { ok = true; } else { $("#ajax_cal").html(response); ok = false; }
```

Also be aware you have double letters in your "parametros" but I'm sure that was intentional (i.e. tiitle and not title etc).

Comment: this may be the case, but it's not the reason his script is failing to do what he wants it to do. see periklis's answer.

Comment: Thanks Jhon, that was left that way intentionally just so I can receive these values in PHP. The problem is getting the return value